# Растянуть элементы

Tags: html, css, frontend, flexbox

У меня есть горизонтальный список (количество элементов может быть разным). Каждый элемент списка состоит из заголовка, длина которого зависит от количества текста в нём, и кнопки фиксированной длины. Элементы идут вплотную друг за другом без отступов. Расстояние от кнопки до заголовка находится в диапазоне от 40 пикселей до 60 пикселей в зависимости от того, достаточно ли места в контейнере. То есть, например, если элементы списка с расстоянием 60 пикселей между заголовком и кнопкой помещаются в ширину контейнера, то отступ должен быть `60px`. А если не помещаются, то отступ должен быть меньше, например `50px`, вплоть до `40px`.

То есть вёрстка примерно такая:

```css
.list {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-flex;
}

.title {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 40px;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li class="item">
    <h3 class="title">Первый</h3>
    <button class="btn">+</button>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <h3 class="title">Второй</h3>
    <button class="btn">+</button>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <h3 class="title">Третий</h3>
    <button class="btn">+</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Но так расстояние между заголовком и кнопкой всегда `40px`, даже когда ширина контейнера позволяет вставить отступ `60px`. Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли как-то сделать, чтобы отступ менялся в зависимости от того, помещаются ли элементы в строку?

Answer (score 0):

Решение:

1. Сделать элемент *item* грид-контейнером
2. Задать грид-контейнеру шаблон колонок: *1fr minmax(0, 20px) auto*
3. Кнопку *btn* **явно** расположить в третьей колонке
4. Чтобы после этого кнопка *btn* не растягивалась на всю высоту грид-контейнера нужно задать ей собственное выравнивание по вертикали (*align-self*) либо задать общее выравнивание по вертикали для грид-контейнера (*align-items*).

Пример на основе вашего кода:

```
.list {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-flex;
}

.item {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr minmax(0, 20px) auto;
}

.title {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 40px;
}

.btn {
  grid-column: 3 / 4;
  align-self: center;
  display: inline-block;
}
```